# Enterprise Mac Mini Server - Remote Desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, server.app, apple-remote-desktop

Just purchased a Mac Mini server. Is there a way that we can allow for multiple sessions for Xcode development within the server?  Would RealVNC allow multiple remote sessions? If so how many?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get two graphical interface log in sessions simultaneously on OS X (server.app or without server.app) and there is no configuration needed as this is the default settings. Just use any VNC client and set up two or more users local to the server.

You'll want to set up the Mac Mini with Xcode Server running and then have each developer run Xcode locally. When they make code changes, you can have the server compile things "continuous integration" style.

Similarly, you could just run your own CI infrastructure on the Mini running whatever OS you wish, but count on the server to only let two workers (either one local and one remote or both remote) to run Xcode GUI itself from each Mac.

Comment: That helps a lot, it sounds like you would recommended Apple's built-in Remote management tools, is there a specific guide you would recommend for setting it up with Active Dir?

Comment: ARD is expensive to just run VNC. I'd pay for Screens app if you just need remote control of one or more and want a quality piece of supported software. There are plenty of free viewers as well that you can start with if you don't want to spend any budget. Setting up Active Dir is about three chapters in the server book. Best to read up and ask specific questions in another thread.